# Importing AnyType elements in EMF

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, emf, ecore

I am building an XML importer using the Eclipse Modeling Framework (EMF). To that end, I had EMF generate me an Ecore model from my XSD metamodel and generate the corresponding Java classes from the Ecore model. Now I am reading in an XML file conforming to my XSD schema and got stuck at the following issue: Creating object instances for all types defined in the XSD schema works perfectly well and I get a nice Java object (instance) hierarchy, but I can't manage to create instances of "AnyType" Elements.
So say I have the following XML:

```
<XMLFile xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="My_xsd_file.xsd" FileName="Example.xml" SchemaVersion="1.10" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Version>2.1</Version>
    <AdditionalInformation someAttribute="someValue" />
    <AdditionalInformation>
        <SomeChildElement>
            <ChildA>Some content</ChildA>
            <ChildB>Some content</ChildB>
        </SomeChildElement>
    </AdditionalInformation>
</XMLFile>
```

`XMLFile` and `Version` are types defined in the XSD schema; I can instantiate the generated `XMLFile` Java object, it has a reference to a `Version` object which I can instantiate as well. It even has a reference to `AdditionalInformation`, but because `AdditionalInformation` has been declared of type `xs:anyType` in the XSD schema, the reference `AdditionalInformation` of `XMLFile` points to an `EObject` which itself has no references (so I cannot add its children to it) and one cannot add references to `EObject`. Here is my code to set these references:

```
for (EReference reference : object.eClass().getEAllReferences()) {
    if (reference.getName().toLowerCase().equals(childNode.getNodeName().toLowerCase())) {
    EClass type = Utils.getInstantiableEClass(reference.getEReferenceType());
        if (type != null && reference.isChangeable()) {
            if (reference.isMany()) {
                EList list = (EList)object.eGet(reference);
                EObject obj = EcoreUtil.create(type);
                if(obj.getClass().equals(EObjectImpl.class)) {
                    obj = xmlFactory.createAnyType();
                }
                //recursiveImport(childNode, obj);
                list.add(obj);
                ...
```

So when I noticed this doesn't work with EObjects, I create an `AnyType` object instead (see code above), as [this article](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364302/Binding-XML-to-Java) says that's what AnyType objects are for.
However, I cannot set the `AnyType` object's references either:

```
if (object instanceof AnyType) {
    NodeList children = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
        Node childNode = children.item(i);
        switch (childNode.getNodeType()) {
        case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            AnyType childObj = xmlFactory.createAnyType();
            recursiveImport(childNode, childObj);
            Entry entry = FeatureMapUtil.createEntry(xmlPackage.getAnyType_Any(), childObj);
            ((FeatureMap) object.eGet(xmlPackage.getAnyType_Any())).add(entry); // throws exception
            ((AnyType) object).getAny().add(entry); // throws exception
            ...
```

This throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: The feature 'any's type 'EFeatureMapEntry' does not permit a value of type 'AnyType'
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EStructuralFeatureImpl$BasicFeatureMapEntry.validate(EStructuralFeatureImpl.java:3213)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.FeatureMapUtil.createEntry(FeatureMapUtil.java:174)
```

I am confused. Isn't the `AnyType` object supposed to do exactly that? Allow an arbitrary number of `AnyType` children? **Do you know how to turn XML anyType-hierarchies into EMF-generated Java instances?**

P.S.: I read https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/536670/ and http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/docs/presentations/EclipseCon/EclipseCon2006_EMF_XML_Binding.pdf, to no avail.

Comment: can you add your specific *.ecore file that you created? It might be that you mixed up some classes between the actual xml ecore model directly from emf and your own.

Comment: @Mad Matts: The generated .ecore file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B10MbhsMWfryMHNRUXpfUnlmNUU/view?usp=sharing), the corresponding xsd file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B10MbhsMWfryMmxyeHhBUEE2Zk0/view?usp=sharing).